# Cloning a Secondary Repo and NOT having it track on Github

Tags: git, github, testing, git-branch, tracking

Bear with me as the answer may seem simple (it does, intuitively, to me, but I have to double-check).

I am a junior dev at a company and have already cloned our repo from GitHub and set up tracking, so my code and branches are connected to our company's source repo. Great.

But I am taking a styled-components course so that I can be more useful when helping with styling changes, and I want to clone a secondary version of the repo to my computer that will not track with the source - just a private, locally-run version where I can practice styling (and another coding, if necessary).
Is it as simple as cloning the repo again, in a different area of my computer, and not setting up tracking? Or will there be an issue because I already have this same repo cloned and following in another area of my device?

I know I can set up a testing branch for myself and delete it without ever merging it - but I'm still curious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, you could create a branch for this use case, but also another way is to [create a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) from the original repo, which is a copy of a repository. Forking a repository allows you to freely experiment with changes without affecting the original project. That would be better than cloning it two times.

Comment: Thanks Narges! I think this will work nicely for me, then, but I do have a follow-up Q:

If I just fork off of my original repo (that is tracking on github) to one that is not, and practice in there, will I be able to easily switch back to the original repo when I have to do actual work in our source code?

In simpler terms, is it easy to switch between the forked repo (for practice) and the original repo (for actual code that I intend to commit)?

Comment: A Fork is a separate repo that is _based_ off of the original. The fork could be created with the intention of moving in a different direction compared to the original repo; the fork could also be used to implement changes by a different group of developers, which is later requested to be merged into the original repo in the future. [See this question around forks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939843/what-does-it-mean-to-fork-on-github).

Comment: @Leonardo Alves Machado also explains in `2.` of this answer the typical purposes of a fork.

Comment: @DanielPascale    Yes, of course. These two concepts(fork & branch) are kind of separated from each other. When you fork from a repo, a forked repo will be created in your personal Github account(which you could clone from it), and you could practice there, but no changes will be committed to the original repo, so there is nothing to worry about. Keep in mind that fork is not like a branch; it means you cannot checkout between your forked repo and the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I think, to achieve your objectives, you can:

1. Clone the repository in another folder - just be sure to play with it and never push it...
2. Make a fork - this will create your own copy of the repository, and you will be able to commit, push, create branches and so on. You will be able to even create pull requests if, at some point in the future, you desire to add some of the stuff you have been playing to the main repository
3. Create a branch for your experiments. This way you will be able to isolate your changes without doing any harm to the main code. This means you don't need to clone the repository again - you can just switch branches whenever you need.

I think you can judge which one fits best for you. Usually, when I do proof of concepts, I choose either to create a branch or a fork (depending on the amount of work needed), but it is up to you...

Answer (score 0):

> [I] want to clone a secondary version of the repo to my computer that will not track with the source...

If you want a separate copy of the repo that "is not tracked" the you can `clone` the repo to another directory and remove the `.git/` directory that is downloaded as part of the `clone`.

---

> will there be an issue because I already have this same repo cloned and tracking in another area of my device?

No, but be aware that any changes you make there will not be reflected within the repo, as tracked by `git`.

---

> I also know I can set up a testing branch for myself, and delete it without ever merging it - but I'm still curious.

You can create a branch, and check the branch out, with:

```
$ git branch <branch-name>
$ git checkout <branch-name>
```

If you want to complete wipe away and delete your local changes you once are done experimenting you can run:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

But be **warned** that this will wipe away your local changes.